# Logical operators from Array[object..]

Tags: typescript, logic, logical-operators

i'm currently work with Boolean And logical operators like this code

FYI i want to convert object.Value , object.Logic in array to do Logical operator. Example : object1.logic object.operators object2.logic as true or false

```
const input: Array<any> = [
    {
        type: "basic",
        value: true,
        logic: "or"
    },
    {
        type: "basic",
        value: false,
        logic: "and"
    },
    {
        type: "basic",
        value: true,
        logic: "and"
    },
```

i want expect result same as

```
 true || false && true
```

Anyone got an idea for this problem ?

Comment: I think question needs more working explanation what you want to achieve.

Comment: @vaira i want to convert  object.Value , object.Logic in array to do Logical operator.  Example : object1.logic object.operators object2.logic      as     true or false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to run `reduce` operator and return a new operator object that will have the logic of previous operator and value or current computation.

```js
let input = [{
    type: "basic",
    value: true,
    logic: "or"
  },
  {
    type: "basic",
    value: false,
    logic: "and"
  },
  {
    type: "basic",
    value: true,
    logic: "and"
  }
]

// if type does not matter 

let result = input.reduce((op1, op2) => ({
  logic: op2.logic,
  value: op1.logic === 'or' ? op1.value || op2.value : op1.value && op2.value
}));
// if you have more than ||- && operations you can create function with switch case and call it here.

console.log(result);
```

If you want to have control on operation sequence:

```js
let input = [{
    type: "basic",
    value: true,
    logic: "or"
  },
  {
    type: "basic",
    value: false,
    logic: "and"
  },
  {
    type: "basic",
    value: true,
    logic: "and"
  }
]

// logic: and - or
// operation: (boolean, boolean) =>  boolean; 
let processOperation = (logic, operation, arr, op) => {
  // if emplty return first
  if (!arr.length) return [op];

  let prevOp = arr[arr.length - 1];

  if (prevOp.logic === logic) {
    // remove prevous and replace with operation result
    arr.pop()
    arr.push({
      logic: op.logic,
      value: operation(prevOp.value, op.value)
    });
  } else {
    arr.push(op); // if operation logic not matched push it in for future processing
  }
  return arr;
}



let result = input
  .reduce(processOperation.bind(this, 'and', (a, b) => a && b), [])
  .reduce(processOperation.bind(this, 'or', (a, b) => a || b), []);
// here you are deciding the order by the squence in the chiain

// result[0].value will be the solution
console.log('answer', result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but may i ask will this cause precedence of logical problem ?  
for example We have to done the   && before ||

Comment: are you saying there is only two operation that is && and || , here you want that && should be processed before ||, right?

Comment: @varia  Yes it is